# How to make a tab automatically appear upon loading up the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of tabs that look like this in my HTML:

```
<div class = "tab">
    <button id = "Hom" class = "tablinks" onclick = "openTab(event, 'Home')">Home</button>
    <button id = "Con" class = "tablinks" onclick = "openTab(event, 'Conjugations')">Conjugations</button>
    <button id = "AutoCon" class = "tablinks" onclick = "openTab(event, 'Auto Conjugator')">Auto Conjugator</button>
</div>
    <div id = "Home" class = "tabcontent">
        <center>
            <img src = "http://youth-portal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/online-courses-of-French.jpg" height = "283.5" width = "567">
        </center>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {

    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

I want to make the home tab appear first when the page loads so that the user does not have to click the tab. I have tried it in CSS but it does not seem to be working. How do you do this with CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: By looking at what your code does you should be able to add an `active` class the the `#Hom` button and give the `#Home` div `style="display: block"` either inline or in your css.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example;
https://codepen.io/curthusting/pen/vpeqWp?editors=1000

I would suggest instead of modifying styles with javascript, i.e.
`tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";` & `document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";`
 control it with css;

```
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
}
.tabcontent.active {
    display: block;
}

.tablinks {
    background: #fff;
}
.tablinks.active {
    background: #5fba7d;
}
```

Then modify your initial html like this

```
<div class="tab">
  <button id="Home" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'HomePanel')">Home</button>
  <button id="Con" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'ConjugationsPanel')">Conjugations</button>
  <button id="AutoCon" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'AutoConPanel')">Auto Conjugator</button>
</div>
<div id="HomePanel" class="tabcontent active">
  <center>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <img src="http://youth-portal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/online-courses-of-French.jpg" height="283.5" width="567">
  </center>
</div>
<div id="ConjugationsPanel" class="tabcontent">
  <center>
    <h1>Conjugations</h1>
    <img src="http://youth-portal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/online-courses-of-French.jpg" height="283.5" width="567">
  </center>
</div>
<div id="AutoConPanel" class="tabcontent">
  <center>
    <h1>Auto Conjugator</h1>
    <img src="http://youth-portal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/online-courses-of-French.jpg" height="283.5" width="567">
  </center>
</div>
```

and your javascript would look like this

```
// move these outside the `openTab()` so we can cache them and not retrieve them every time the active tab is changed 
const tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
const tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");

function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  [].forEach.call(tabcontent, function(el) {
      el.classList.remove("active");
  });
  [].forEach.call(tablinks, function(el) {
      el.classList.remove("active");
  });

    document.getElementById(tabName).classList += " active";
    evt.currentTarget.classList += " active";
}
```